# Identifying cosets of normal subgroups in $UT_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

From Artin's *Algebra* (problem 2.10.1):

> Let $G$ be the group of invertible real upper triangular $2\times 2$ matrices. Determine whether or not the following conditions describe normal subgroups $H$ of $G$. If they do, use the First Isomorphism Theorem to identify the quotient group $G/H$.
>   (a) $a_{11}=1$ (b) $a_{12}=0$ (c) $a_{11}=a_{22}$ (d) $a_{11}=a_{22}=1$.

I determined that $H\trianglelefteq G$ in the case of (a), (c), and (d). Moreover, in the case of (a) and (c), I found that $G/H\cong \mathbb{R}^\times$.

I'm a little bit confused about what it means to use the FIT to identify $G/H$. Does this mean I need to find a surjective homomorphism $\varphi$ from $G$ to some other group $Z$ such that $H=\ker\varphi$ so that $\varphi:G/H\to Z$ is an isomorphism (and hence $G/H\cong Z$)? I'm not quite sure because this only identifies $G/H$ up to isomorphism, but not explicitly.

This is what I did for (a) and (c). For (a) I let $\varphi$ be the surjective map $\varphi:G\to\mathbb{R}^\times$ where $\varphi(A)=a_{11}$. For (c), I let $\varphi$ be the surjective map $\varphi:G\to\mathbb{R}^\times$ where $\varphi(A)=a_{11}a_{22}^{-1}$.

I came up with these maps by thinking about the explicit descriptions of the cosets of $H$.

I haven't quite identified $G/H$ in (d), but I suspect that $G/H\cong \mathbb{R}^\times\times\mathbb{R}^\times$. As $A,B\in G$ are in the same coset of $H$ if and only if $a_{11}=b_{11}$ and $a_{22}=b_{22}$.

EDIT: For some reason I can't leave comments, so they are part of the edit.
-My question is: Is this approach of finding surjective homorphisms in order to identify $G/H$ up to isomorphism what Artin is asking me to do? This seems odd to me as describing the cosets explicitly is easy. (So I guess I'm also asking what the point of this exercise is.)

Comment: Sounds like you are making great progress, but what is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested, I think $\varphi:G \to \mathbb{R}^\times \times \mathbb{R}^\times$ defined by $\varphi(A) = (a_{11}, a_{22})$ works for (d). Just be sure to verify that it is indeed a homomorphism.

When we "identify" or "classify" groups, we usually mean "find the isomorphism class" of the group. You express a concern that we identify $G/H$ up to isomorphism but not explicitly, but we are primarily concerned with the group structure, not what elements are used to represent the group elements.

Identifying the cosets explicitly is a good first step. For (d), I see that you notice that it is "matrices that share the same upper-left and bottom-right entries." However, how do you know that as a result, the group structure of $G/H$ is the same as that of $\mathbb{R}^\times \times \mathbb{R}^\times$? Without the isomorphism theorem, you can't just conclude that.

Disclaimer: this is my first year taking algebra, so please correct me if I have said anything inaccurate/incorrect.

Comment: Your second paragraph was very informative for me! It cleared my confusions about this and a few other exercises.

Comment: What about $(b)$ ? Is $G/H \cong \mathbb R^{+}$ ? It's my guess, not sure about a proof. Is it similar to $(a)$ ?

Comment: @noob (b) is not asked since it is not an normal subgroup.